# How to add a html content in json

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, css

Json format

```
{ 
   "articledescription":"<p>Lyric 1</br>Lyric 2</br>Lyric 3</br>Lyric 4</br></p>"
}
```

Output what i got after execution:

```
<p>Lyric 1</br>Lyric 2</br>Lyric 3</br>Lyric 4</br></p>
```

Can anyone explain how to get this output:

```
Lyric 1
Lyric 2
Lyric 3
Lyric 4
```

Comment: you can use `ng-bind-html`

Comment: Its not `</br>` It should be `<br />` OR `<br>`....

Comment: Tried to use the value as an array and then ng-repeat on the same?

Comment: If your output is actually showing the tags to the user then the problem isn't with your JSON, it's that whatever is consuming the JSON is treating that string as text rather than HTML. Please [edit] your question to show the relevant JavaScript.